# Why is the tracks array of an AVURLAsset empty after loading?

Tags: cocoa, avfoundation

I'm trying to get the natural size of the video track of an `AVURLAsset`. So I'm loading the asset `tracks` with `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:`. In the completion handler, when the status is `AVKeyValueStatusLoaded` I look at the `asset.tracks` and it is empty. I'm expecting to find at least an audio and a video track. Why is the tracks array empty?

Here is my code:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    __block BOOL loaded = NO;
    AVURLAsset *asset;
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/resources/http-streaming/examples/bipbop_4x3/bipbop_4x3_variant.m3u8"];
        asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
        [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tracks"] completionHandler:^{
            loaded = YES;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSError *error = nil;
                AVKeyValueStatus status = [asset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error];
                if (status == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded)
                    NSLog(@"asset.tracks (%ld): %@", [asset.tracks count], asset.tracks);
                else
                    NSLog(@"error (%ld): %@", status, error);
            });
        }];
    }

    while (!loaded)
        [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];

    return 0;
}
```

Running this code on Mountain Lion 10.8.1 logs this:

```
asset.tracks (0): (
)
```

**UPDATE** Some people pointed to me that I may not get tracks because I'm using a *HTTP Live Streaming* URL. So any way (using tracks or not) to get the size of the currently playing video would be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the asset is served with *HTTP Live Streaming* it does not have any track. Another way of retrieving the video size is to observe the player item `presentationSize` property with KVO:

```
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset]];
[player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem.presentationSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

Comment: @oxced: I want to get current bitrate of player. Is there anyway to do so with HLS?

Comment: @0xced: Is this an OSX-only issue? I don't see a problem with this on iOS.

Comment: I just tried that code on bot OS X 10.11.4 and iOS 9.3 and I get the same result: 0 tracks!